# Regex to capture episode number

Tags: python, regex

What is wrong with the following regular expression I have:

```
s = "s4, ep2 -- The one"
>>> re.search(r'(Episode|Ep?\.?)?\s?(\d{0,})', s, re.IGNORECASE).group(2)
''
```

I am trying to capture the `2` from the `"S4, Ep2"`. I thought the `Ep?\.?\s?d{0,}` would capture it but it seems like I'm missing something.

Here are other example inputs that might be entered:

```
Episode 2
Ep. 2
E. 2
2
Season 4, E 2 -- Hello
```

All of the above should come out as "2"

Comment: You made every thing optional. That's the problem.

Comment: @revo well - it is. For example, someone could just enter in "3" and the episodeNumber would then be "3".

Comment: Then how would you know that `3` is the episode number and not something else?

Comment: @revo it's a user input. The input is called "Episode" and has a variety of formats.

Comment: You even let user to enter nothing. If you need the number just use `\d+`.

Comment: So if input is `Season 123 Hello 678` then what will be episode number?

Comment: @anubhava probably empty if there's any ambiguity.

Comment: You should re-study your requirements. They're not precise. At this point I can say you need a regex like `^(.*Episode|.*Ep?\.?)?\s?(\d+)`

Comment: From your given examples it looks like you're trying to match the last number in a string although that'd change if the last examples title includes a number. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version is working.  We can try matching on `Episode`, `Ep`, or just `E`, followed by an optional dot and/or space.  Then, capture an episode number.

```
s = "s4, ep2 -- The one"
print(re.search(r'(?:Season \d+,\s+)?(?:Episode|Ep|E)?\.?\s?(\d{0,})',
    s, re.IGNORECASE).group(1))

2
```

Comment: thanks, this doesn't work on the bottom two entries though -- capturing just the number itself `2`, or the Episode with just "`E `.

Comment: cool now it seems to work for all except the last one -- `'Season 4, E 2 -- Hello'`

Comment: @David542 More like a cheap hack.  Next time you ask, make sure you highlight _all_ edge cases at the very beginning.  This way, we won't have to circle back with you so many times to find the answer.